# Three table relationship - uniqueness across three IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

```
Table A (int id, String name)
Table B (int id, String processName)
Table C (int id, String containerName)
```

The relationship here is this - Objects from table A can have objects from table B. Objects from table B can have objects from table C. Objects from Table A can have objects from table C. Essentially - I have a "triangle" work flow.

So the idea is to have junction tables that mimic this:

```
Table A_B (aId, bId)
Table B_C (bId, cId)
Table A_C (aId, cId)
```

I also have a business requirement that requires the combination of aId, bId, and cId will be unique. If I had a "flat" table, it would look like this:

```
Table X (aId, bId, cId)
    Unique key on the three
```

Now, obviously, I can have a primary key on each of the reference table ids and a primary key on the two columns in the junction tables. I would prefer not smashing my data points together to adhere to the business requirements. I want to keep the objects decoupled.

But how would I go about representing this relationship further to also adhere to the business requirement? I've been reading up on composite keys, I am not sure if that is my solution or not.

Comment: The business requirement makes it sound like there is an underlying entity.  Why not just create `X`?

Comment: It's hard to explain - The reality is that A, B and C are absolutely unique entities in the proposed model. The issue is the model is "graph" like - entity A can add entity B, entity B can be assigned to many entity C objects, entity A chooses entity C objects later. The issue very well might be the proposed model. It's also hard when I cannot say what the entities are :(